# Recover a file deleted accidentally, in a git repository without committing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, delete-file, recovery

Seems like I have just deleted an important *.py* file by accident, inside a remote ubuntu server, via my VS Code. The file was inside a git repository. But unfortunately, I hadn't committed the changes. Is there any possible way to recover the file?
I'm imagining if there is somewhere in the *.git* or another folder, which stores the recently deleted files if I'm lucky.

I tried recovering it with TestDisk, but I couldn't find my file anywhere there.

Comment: Was that only copy of that file on a remote server? Did it ever make its way to your local PC?

Comment: Sadly the answer is no. I checked everywhere and couldn't find any copy of it. @JovanPerovic

Comment: If you didn't commit (or stash or etc) anything, Git has no knowledge of the file.